# Postgres Fill In Empty Data When Aggregating

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I am aggregating a total amount, separating days, and then dumping that data into  chart. Example query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM post_created_date) as report_year, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM post_created_date) AS regweek, COUNT(post_id) as post_count 
FROM TableA 
GROUP BY report_year, regweek
```

This works fine, but on some days there is no data, giving the chart gaps

```
1/14  -  5
1/15  -  7
1/18  -  4
```

How can I also include dates that have no event report 0 on that date?

Comment: You need a _calendar table_ (which can be generated on the fly by `generate_series()` )

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `left outer join` for this purpose.  The idea is to create all combinations of year and week and then join to your query.  This is pretty easy in Postgres with `generate_series()`.  Something like:

```
select yw.yr, yw.wk, coalesce(r.post_count, 0) as post_count
from (select distinct EXTRACT(YEAR FROM post_created_date) as yr,
             generate_series(1, 52) as wk
      from TableA
     ) yw left outer join
     (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM post_created_date) as report_year,
             EXTRACT(WEEK FROM post_created_date) AS regweek, COUNT(post_id) as post_count 
      FROM TableA 
      GROUP BY report_year, regweek
     ) r
     on yw.yr = report_year and yw.wk = regweek;
```